# "class file for org.junit.rules.TestRule not found" Despite Junit being defined in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, junit, java-8, java-17

Upgrading a project from jdk 8 to jdk 17.. When I run mvn clean install on a project, it fails with the error "class file for org.junit.rules.TestRule not found." There are no direct imports of this junit class within the directory that is failing, and the TestRule interface doesnt even seem to be used within the entire service. The junit dependency was defined in the pom.xml for the project.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

and the line of the failure doesn't seem very related: mongodExecutable.withExposedPorts(port);

Some other dependencies:

Maven compiler plugin is v3.5.1.
org.testcontainers dependency at v1.16.3

Have tried altering junit versioning in both files, as well as updating the surefire dependency to 3.0.0-M5 which I saw on another post. Have searched for possible deprecation in the libraries within the file that fails, as well as conflicts between older versions of dependencies/plugins and jdk 17.

Comment: please post the full pom file here....